# Corrupt heap memory

Tags: c#, heap-memory

I'm having issues with heap getting corrupt and after some help.

I have a drop down combo box where data source is a simple list of directories on a network drive.

I then call partial class to apply a filter .i.e to display in the list only rows that match types characters. This is where the problem is. It's very random. It can work 10 or 15 times in a row and then stop with heap corruption error. Or stop few times in a row and then work again.

I'm very inexperienced C# developer so please be with me!!

I initiate list as per below:

```
List<string> arrProjectList;

this.List = Directory.GetDirectories(sRootDirectoryPrograms).Select(Directory => Path.GetFileName(Directory)).ToList();
```

Then within my partial class i do the following:

```
 public void DropDownTextUpdated()
    {
      string filter_param = SelectJobDropdown.Text;

      if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter_param))
        {
            //reset some variables
        }
        else
        {
            if (filter_param != null)
            {
                List<string> filteredItems = this.arrProjectList.FindAll(x => x.ToLower().Contains(filter_param.ToLower()));

                if (filteredItems.Count == 0)
                {
                    //reset some variables
                }
                else
                {   
                     /*************************************/ 
                    //this is where issue occurs on random!!!
                     /*************************************/                    
                    SelectJobDropdown.DataSource = filteredItems;
                    SelectJobDropdown.IntegralHeight = true;
                }

                SelectJobDropdown.DroppedDown = true;
                Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;

                // remove automatically selected first item
                SelectJobDropdown.SelectedIndex = -1;

                SelectJobDropdown.Text = filter_param;

                // set the position of the cursor
                SelectJobDropdown.SelectionStart = filter_param.Length;
                SelectJobDropdown.SelectionLength = 0;
            }

    }
```

UPDATED:

Error details:
Hopefully this is enough details.

System.AccessViolationException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

As i said its random but when it happens, it takes place as soon as I type a single characters.

I read about it some debugging but no idea how to tackle this one!

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: please add the full exception information including the exception call stack to the question.

Comment: I remember this exception was regular theese days. I think, the resolution was not using DataSource, but using "Items" property.

Comment: TcKs thanks. I'm away from the laptop at the moment but will look into it when I get home. Cheers

Comment: Interesting. To make life easier, I moved part of the code into another forms with just simple combo box and I'm unable to replicate the problem. I'm slowly moving other blocks of code until I'm able to replicate. Is there an easier way? Like debugging tool which would stop exactly at the line where leak occurs?